# UITextView text alignment

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uitextview, text-alignment

After the show segue from UITableView to UITextView

[image: show segue from UITableView]

I have the following problem:
If i clear constraints for the UITextView the result is, of course unsatisfied:

[image: UITextView without constraints]

But the good part of this – is starting from the first line at the top.

If I try to add suggested constraints to the UITextView I got this:

[image: UITextView with suggested constraints]

The problem is that the text begins not from the start.

What I need to get after segue page with text aligned to top like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add your own constraints to bottom bar.
first you need to place your textview up the bottom bar
[image]

Then add your own constraint to bar(drug with right button from textview on tabor).

[image]

Add vertical spacing

[image]

Then add other missing constraints

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: I tried so, but the result is the same – text doesn't showing from the beginning. 
By the way in your result screenshot – the UITextView does not start from the beginning also.

Comment: It didn't start from begin, because i'm already scroll a little bit. In your case it placed under the top bar, so you can add the same constraints in the top, like in bottom(Vertical spacing to navigation bar)

Answer (score 0):

I believe embedding the textView in a scrollView will fix the issue and allow for the viewing of all the text.